# What will be Time Complexity if we use include function inside the some function of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

As we know that Array.prototype.some() and Array.prototype.includes() has time complexity of o(n). Now I want to know that what if I will use include inside some method. The time complexity will be linear or quadratic?

```
function checkDublicate (arr1, arr2) {
return arr1.some(item => arr2.includes(item));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *O(mn)*, where *m* is `arr1.length` and *n* is `arr2.length`.

Comment: Well, if one is oversimplifying things (which is okay in Big-O notation), then yes, it's O(n^2).

Comment: But ideally lengths of the arrays are independent, so the variables are different.

Comment: Got it if the length of both array is same then it will be  O(n^2) else O(m * n ).

Answer (score 1):

Considering the worst case scenario, if `arr2` has no items from `arr1`, all `n` elements will be searched in `arr2`, with each search having `O(n)` complexity. Overall complexity will be `O(n^2)` (assuming `n` elements in either array).

Answer (score 0):

It will be Quadratic TC ie. O(mn)

for array of length n

- `some()` has TC of `O(n)`
- `includes()` has TC of `O(n)`

In your case, You are using two nested loops logic wise so Time Complexity will be the product of both TC

`TC(checkDublicate) = TC(some(arr1.length)) * TC(includes(arr2.length))`

`TC(checkDublicate) = O(arr1.length * arr2.length)`